# Protractor: How can I get the next tag

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

Is it possible to get an element after another element?  (not subelements)

HTML code:

```
<input id="first-input" type="text"/>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<input id="second-input" type="text"/>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<input id="third-input" type="text"/>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the `ul` following `element(by.id('second-input'))`?

Here's my understanding:

```
element(by.id('second-input')).element(by.tagName('ul')) // This doesn't work because this looks for sub-elements in <input id="second-input">
element.all(by.tagName('ul')).first() // This doesn't work because it gets the 'ul' following <input id="first-input">
element(by.id('second-input')).element.all(by.tagName('ul')) // This doesn't work because this looks for all 'ul' elements as sub-elements of <input id="second-input">
```

In my case, these 'ul's don't have unique ids, or anything unique.

Comment: Give the uls unique ids. Since it is not nested, javascript will not understand your function

Comment: the ULs are generated by third party library.  I don't want to touch it.  Any other options?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`by.xpath()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath) and ask for the *following `ul` sibling*:

```
element(by.id('second-input')).element(by.xpath('following-sibling::ul'));
```

Or, in one go:

```
element(by.xpath('//input[@id="second-input"]/following-sibling::ul'));
```

---

Another option would be to use [`by.css()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css) with an [*adjacent sibling selector*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
element(by.css('#second-input + ul'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath selectors is not a better choice as it slows down the element finding mechanism.

It will be very simple with [protractor-css-booster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-css-booster) plugin. This plugin will help you to find sibling elements with css selectors.

Download the plugin with

```
npm install --save protractor-css-booster
```

Add the plugin in your configuration file:

```
exports.config = {
  // ... the rest of your config
  plugins: [
    {
      // The module name
      package: "protractor-css-booster"
    }
  ]
};
```

Now, you can find your element like:

```
const ulElem=element(by.css('#second-input')).element(by.followingSibling('ul')); \\ returns the first div
```